# Wordpress Multilingual plugin subdirectory lanauge

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, subdirectory

I'm currently trying to install a Wordpress website, and providing it through multiple languages. I've found a bunch of plugins to manage the translation.
But I'm still getting stuck to setup WordPress to be able to have http://www.mywebsite.com/en/ and/or http://www.mywebsite.com/de/.
I've found the language switch redirecting to the same page, with the correct subdirectory, but I got an error 404. It looks something should be enabled globally on Wordpress, or even changing the Apache configuration?
Thank you for your future help.

Answer (score 0):

You can User [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/weglot/) for making multilingual you site.

Comment: Even with this plugin I have the same error, when trying to switch from the default language, which doesn't have the language subdirectory prefix like http://www.mywebsite.com/mypost/01 to http://www.mywebsite.com/de/mypost/01